# How do I reorder my dropdown list in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdown list in my MVC 5 application, which is a rating scale from 1 to 10, however  10 is just below 1 instead of being at the end of the list. So that the list runs 1, 10, 2, 3 etc. Is there a way of rectifying this? My list isn't hardcoded, it's being populated from a database.

Below is my MVC code for the dropdown list:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating, "Rating", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })

@Html.DropDownList("Rating", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
```

Comment: Sort it on the server by converting the values to integer instead of string, and then return the collection.

Comment: The items in the dropdown will be rendered in the same order you return them from the database.

Comment: My values in the database are tinyint for the rating index and nvarchar for rating in the rating table, which is the same value as rating in my main table. I tried changing the dropdown order within the rating table but it just reverted back to to 1, 10, 2 etc again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort them before converting to drop-down list.

```
var values = db.Rating.OrderByDescending(o => o.Rate).ToList(); 
var dropdownlist = values.Select(s => new SelectListItem{Value = s.Rate.ToString(), Name = s.Name}).ToList(); 
ViewBag.List = dropdownlist;

//in your view
Html.DropwDownList("Rating", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.List);
```

If your rating is stored as a string, then you should cast it to int before ordering. Try this:

```
var values = db.Rating.Select(s => new {Rate = Convert.ToInt32(s.Rate}, Id = s.Id).OrderByDescending(o => o.Rate).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vsevolod, I'm pretty new to this, can you tell me where to place the first three lines of code?

Comment: @Scanner The first two lines should be in your controller or service or wherever you are getting your data. The third line will be in you controller action

Comment: Thats great, thanks again Vsevolod. Sorry to be a pest, it orders my list, but 10 is still the second item instead of being the last item.

Comment: @Scanner Do you have a rating property as a string or int?

Comment: Theres two tables, the rating table has rating index which is a tiny int and rating which is an nvarchar, the main table which gets populated with the saved rating value has a rating field which is also an nvarchar

Comment: @Scanner ok, the problem here is that the actual rating is a string and it's sorted by string sorting rules. I will update the answer with the code that might help you